# /usr/local/share/timidity/timidity.cfg: No such file or directory

Tags: ffmpeg, midi

Timidity version is TiMidity++-2.14.0, and here is my install commond:

```
./configure && make && make install
```

Then I run the commond

```
timidity song.mid -Ow -o | ffmpeg -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 64k song.mp3
```

and it returns error:

> /usr/local/share/timidity/timidity.cfg: No such file or directory timidity: Can't read any configuration file. Please check /usr/local/share/timidity/timidity.cfg

"find / -name timidity.cfg", but there is no such file.
I am confused about the error.
Thanks for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/install.html) says:

> TiMidity++ uses Either GUS/patch, or SoundFont (,or both) as the voice data to play. You must get a SoundFont or GUS/patch files, and make the configuration file. You must make the configuration file (*.cfg). By default, timidity.cfg is `/usr/local/share/timidity/timidity.cfg`.

Also see the [Arch documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/timidity).